# Ask about Tab Bar, viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My program have two tabs,

1. I set init variable in viewDidLoad.  ( int A = 0; )
2. I change A = 2 when press button.
3. I switch to tab2 and switch back to tab1,  A is still 2.

How to call viewDidLoad in tab1 again ? ( I want to init variable again when switch back to tab1 .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `-viewWillAppear` delegate method is more suitable for what you want - try to set your variable there.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing much, i could say, You should organize your data better way!

Tabbar viewcontrollers wont be loaded again while switching!
You can handle `ViewWillAppear` though..